# HTML/CSS -lineheight is affecting <br> tag?

Tags: html, css

So I want to do something like this:

[image: Example]

(I'm trying to replicate Amazon just for practice)

But when I tried a much shorter and better method, which is to alter the display to inline-block. Then in order to center it I would make the `line-height` similar to `height`.

But this casues one problem, the "category" word is pushed down too. So it looks like this:

[image: Problem]

This is the code, how should I fix it?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li> <a class="nav-text" href="file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Shop by <br/> category </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-text {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the `display` at all. The `a` should have `{vertical-align:middle;}` set for it and the height and all the rest should be set in a rule for the `li`, not the `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to change the display for the `a` at all. The `a` should have:

```
 { vertical-align:middle; }
```

set for it and the height and all the rest should be set in a rule for the `li`, not the `a`. In fact, some of the other CSS properties can come out as well.

I've also updated the fiddle to move the `p` element you had nested inside the `a` element, so that it is now the parent of the `a` element (a bit more semantically correct).

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lsm4prg/4/

Comment: I literaly just figured that out a second ago! hence why I deleted my comment haha, thanks for eveyrthing!

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the `<br/>` tag you basicly have 2 lines with both a line-height of 100px which causes the big spaces. If you wrap your text in a `<p>` tag with `display: table;` and `vertical-align: middle;` With this code you don't need to use the `line-height` you can resolve this problem. See my fiddle for the updated code:

https://jsfiddle.net/yjjmjya0/

```
.nav-text {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.nav-text p {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

<ul>
   <li> 
     <a class = "nav-text" href=file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> 
      <p>
        Shop by <br/> category 
      </p>
     </a> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `line-height` sets the line height of *each* line. Try using `vertical-align:bottom` instead on the `nav-text` class.

```css
.nav-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color:white;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
li{
  list-style: none; 
  display:inline-block;
}
ul{
  padding:0; 
  background:rgb(35,47,62);
}
```

```html
<ul>
            <li> <a class = "nav-text" href = "file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Shop by <br/> category </a> </li>
  <li> <a class = "nav-text" href = "file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Discussion Forums </a> </li>
  <li> <a class = "nav-text" href = "file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/practice1.html"> Help </a> </li>
</ul>
```